# Rails namespace and reverse routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I have a namespace -admin- and i would like to use the "shorthand" reverse routing for resources that fall under this namespace so for example

without namespace i can do :

```
<%= link_to @user.name, @user %>
```

i want to be able to do the same when the user resource is under the namespace 'admin' WITHOUT doing

```
<%= link_to @user.name, admin_user_path(@user) %> |
```

i was wondering if that is possible, thank you.

*ps : Excuse my lack of a better rails terminology and please feel free to edit this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<%= link_to @user.name, [:admin, @user] %>
```

Same goes for controller helpers like `redirect_to`.

Comment: I already use it in redirect_to, i have no idea why it escaped my mind to try it, or maybe i didn't because it was 4AM in here :D, thank you anyways.